# validate thumbnails using python ( not mostly the same color )

Tags: python, validation, opencv, thumbnails

i'm creating a python script that creates a thumbnail from videos using OpenCV at defined second during the video.
but i need to validate that the thumbnail is created at time when the frame is not almost contains one color like if the thumbnail is white or black
so if the image is not validated i will create another thumbnail.

so any python tool exists to:
1 - validate the thumbnail. 
2- or suggest a second to create thumbnails at.

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest to refine the question into: How to detect that picture is mostly same color with OpenCV.

Comment: No, I don't guess there exists a library for that, However it must be fairly simple to implement.

Comment: Why not calculate the statistics of the pixel colors since you already have the thumbnail in OpenCV (Mat I presume)?

Comment: i dont know alot about calculating that fromt he image so i'm asking for tool that already implement that or can extract that features ,thanks

Comment: @amr just calculate average color and calculate average deviation from it. Lower the deviation more homogeneous is the image.

Comment: @Andrey yes ok,thanks alot.i found the overall deviation value at henrikstroem answer it is very helpfull

Comment: @amr yeah that is exactly it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do that kind of thing using ImageMagick - it's got an `identify` command that can give you the information you need.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

It's a command line tool, so you need to run it as such.